# Crons are starting a few minutes late in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a Laravel program that runs in some docker containers. It has a number of cron jobs in it that run at certain intervals. The cron jobs do consistently run, but they always run late - and considerably late, like three and a half minutes. It's not consistent how late they run - sometimes 3m30s, sometimes 2m51s, sometimes as little as 1m, and everything in between - sometimes nearly five minutes late.

I've added a cron job to the crontab that just writes the time to a log file. This consistently runs either exactly when it should or 1 second late. I added a cron job with the same functionality (just writing the time) in Laravel and it has the delay, so it's not an issue of the job taking time to execute its logic. I added a simple function to bootstrap/app.php [as suggested here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/scheduler-running-with-delay-not-on-time) and it writes with.... well, it's hard to tell. It seems like it's writing with a one second delay, but I'm not certain about that. Here's some output from the log file. Notice that it typically writes at :01 seconds after the minute, but sometimes with :54 or :51, which is very odd to my eye.

> 2021-10-20 17:24:51 app.php2021-10-20 17:25:01 app.php2021-10-20 17:25:54 app.php2021-10-20 17:26:01 app.php2021-10-20 17:27:01 app.php

I've checked my entropy levels [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575413/laravel-scheduler-running-with-delay-not-on-time) and have over 3400 bits, so I don't think that's the issue.

Moreover, when I run a command manually, it also takes several minutes before it starts. I think there's some sort of delay between when the command is issued and when it's executed and that this is affecting manual commands and cron jobs, but I haven't been able to find it yet. Is there a common cause for this? Is there a specific place you'd suggest I look to narrow down my search?

Comment: Can you execute the artisan command manually and in a different terminal immediately run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`. How much entropy is available?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy when checking with things running normally I got 3234. Immediately after executing an artisan command I got 3413. So I remain pretty sure it's not that